# How do I write results of a MySQL query to a text file inside a loop?

Tags: mysql, loops

I have a large database of individuals (say `1000` individuals/ `5,000` records per individual). I'd like to write a couple of fields for each individual (in this example let's say lat and long) to a text file (preferably comma separated).

The algorithm would look like this:

```
foo=select distinct (id) from <table-name>;
for each id in foo
{
smaller_result= select lat,long from <table-name> where id=$id;
write smaller_result to a text file with unique name (e.g. id.txt);
}
```

I can easily code this up in PHP (which I frequently use to interface with MySQL if I cannot run a command line SQL query directly). However, in this case, I need to share the code with a collaborator and have him run it (and he does not have and cannot install php). Also, the database is quite large and cannot easily be uploaded online (which would allow me to run the query through the web). So how else would I accomplish this?

a) Can this algorithm be written as a sql query that can be executed in a command line?

b) If not, can this be written in python such that my collaborator would just run a .py file?

We are both on OSX (Lion) and can access mysql and python from our shell / terminal.

Comment: Hmmm...last I checked Lion ships with PHP so he should already have it installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can output the result of any select query with SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE. This will generate a text file with the output (on the **server**).

So you need to create a single SELECT query which generates the file... I think in your case it can be easily done with a subquery, if not, you can create a stored procedure with a cursor that loops your 'foo' result set and appends it to a temp table, and then use SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE with that table.